# Please help me understand a bit shift operation

Tags: python, bit-shift

```
def different(s):
   x = len(s)
   for i in range(1, 1 << x):
      u.append([s[j] for j in range(x) if (i & (1 << j))])
```

It takes a list and makes different combinations

```
(a,b,c) = ((a,b,c),(a,b),(a,c) ...)
```

But what does the range do? From 1 to what. I don't understand the `"<<"`

and also, `if (i & (1 << j))` what does this do? It checks if i and 2 to the power of j? Doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Lots of people put effort into helping you out.  Deleting this question would result in them losing rep.  If your issue is solved by some other means, leave an answer with your solution and select it when the option becomes available.  Helps people who have similar issues and doesn't penalize those that tried to help.  (also fixed some stuff you were concerned about)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The range function returns a list of numbers from zero to the given number minus one. It also has two- and three-argument forms (see the [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) for more info):

```
range(n) == [0, 1, 2, ..., n - 1]
```

`<<` is the left-shift operator, and has the effect of multiplying the left hand side by two to the power of the right hand side:

```
x << n == x * 2**n
```

Thus the above range function (`range(1, 1 << x)`) returns `[1, 2, 3, ..., 2**x - 1]`.

In the seconds usage of `<<`, the left-shift is being used as a bit-mask. It moves the 1-bit into the *j*-th bit, and performs a bit-wise *and* with *i*, so the result will be non-zero (and pass the `if` test) if and only if the *j*-th bit of *i* is set. For example:

```
j = 4
1 << j = 0b1000 (binary notation)

i = 41 = 0b101001
i & (1 << j) = 0b101001
             & 0b001000
             = 0b001000 (non-zero, the if-test passes)

i = 38 = 0b100110
i & (1 << j) = 0b100110
             & 0b001000
             = 0b000000 (zero, the if-test fails)
```

In short, `x & (1 << y)` is non-zero iff the *y*-th bit of *x* is set.

Answer (score 5):

`<<` is the binary left shift operator. `1 << x` is a way of saying two to the power of x.

Comment: @nils, yes, but `3 << 10` is twice as fast as `3 * 2 ** 10`

Comment: @nils: "so it's the same as 2**x?"?  Please actually try the code.  Please run an experiment.  Please execute it interactively at the Python `>>>` prompt.  You can prove they're the same all by yourself.